# Composition Masking using Python Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I am trying to implement the following ImageMagick command using Python Wand:

```
convert red_image.png  green_image.png  write_mask.png -composite masked_composite.png
```

Here's the example of it in images:

[image]

Any hints?

UPDATE: Here's my solution if anyone ever wonders. Note: not elegant, but works.

```
bash_command = "convert "+str(red_image.png)+" "+str(green_image.png)+" write_mask.png -   composite "+str(red_image.png)+str(green_image.png)+".jpg"
os.system(bash_command)
```

Comment: Put the mask into the alpha channel of the green image and then composite with the red image so that you only have two images to composite. Then you should be able to do that in Wand. You can even put the mask into the alpha channel in Wand.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the [`copy_opacity` composite operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#copyopacity), which takes a black-and-white source image and replaces the alpha channel of the destination image with its contents.

Here's the `apply_mask` function that I use in my projects:

```
def apply_mask(image, mask, invert=False):
    image.alpha_channel = True
    if invert:
        mask.negate()
    with Image(width=image.width, height=image.height, background=Color("transparent")) as alpha_image:
        alpha_image.composite_channel(
            "alpha",
            mask,
            "copy_opacity",
            0, 0)
        image.composite_channel(
            "alpha",
            alpha_image,
            "multiply",
            0, 0)
```

First I make sure that the image we want to apply the mask to has an alpha channel, and check if we want the mask to be inverted or not. Then we replace the alpha channel of a new transparent image using the mask. We do this so we can then combine this resulting alpha channel with any alpha channel already present on the destination image. If we were to apply the mask with `copy_opacity` directly to our image without this intermediary step, it would replace its alpha channel (rather than merge them), clobbering any of its original alpha channel data.